# Server receive message and convert from lower case to upper case

Tags: c, unix

Code to receive message like "hi i am man" and convert it to upper case "HI I AM MAN".

```
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: look at the man page for "toupper()" which will the upper case of a single character.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  It looks like C.  Don't dual tag questions with C and C++ unless you're particularly fond of down-votes (few people like them).  It annoys people when both languages are used in a single question without better justification.  You've not shown your attempt to case-convert the data.  You've not shown how you know that the string read by `read()` is null terminated, so it probably isn't, so your `printf()` will probably print extraneous characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

  n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    buffer[i] = toupper(buffer[i]);
  printf("Here is the message: %s\n", buffer);
```

Comment: how can i find the length of buffer

Comment: The return value 'n' should give you the size of string.

Answer (score 0):

Use toupper and tolower functions for uppercase and lowercase

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <string>         // std::string
#include <locale>         // std::locale, std::toupper
int main (){
  std::locale loc;
  std::string str="Test String.\n";
  for (std::string::size_type i=0; i<str.length(); ++i)
    std::cout << std::toupper(str[i],loc);
return 0;
}
```